# Edit maximum number of characters in R dfSummary (R)

Tags: r, summarytools

I am wondering if it is possible to edit the "Stats/Values" column in dfSummary command of the R package "summarytools". I need to adjust the number of characters displayed in the values (I do not mean the number of factor levels but literally the number of characters) as there is a cut off point defined which not suit my survey data. I have posted a screenshot for an example.

Thanks a lot for your help!

[dfSummary_screenshot_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQksX.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter exactly for this... By default, its value is 25, but you can make it however large you want :)

`dfSummary(dat, max.string.width = 500)`

Comment: I already tried that before. Unfortunately I do not see any difference when I apply that command, no matter if I set it to 500 or 10. The result is the same as in the screenshot above. Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Would you mind opening an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools/issues) for this? It would be easier to take it from there. If you could post a sample of your data either here or on GitHub to make a reproducible example that would also help.

Comment: It appears that the solution found here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61878582/why-does-dfsummary-r-sometimes-plot-factor-levels-in-one-line] is mostly appropriate for that question.
However, is there a possibility to set the `max.string.width` to selected columns in the outcome?