# Why does dfSummary (R) sometimes plot factor levels in one line?

Tags: r, summarytools

Why does `dfSummary` command of the "summarytools" package in R in some cases prints the value labels in one row instead of in row per level?

I cannot provide a reproducible data sample, but here is a Screenshot from `view()` command in R. [Screenshot_dfSummary_view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hdzn.png)

I checked classes, tried to relabel and rename etc. but without success.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible data set. It doesn't have to be your real data. Just some data you make up or find or modify that reproduces the problem. The first step to solving the problem is recreating it.

Comment: i totally agree. but thats also a part of the problem: I cannot reproduce it from scratch. I have received survey data in an .sav file. After import with haven package (I also tried others) I observed the describes behavior. My problem is understanding whats going. on. Why this happens and how to avoid it. The factors in the dataset seem ok. they are well labelled (class "labelled" "factor") and I did check them on white spaces etc. Any ideas anybody?

Comment: If the problem is evident on, say, the first 10 rows of data, then share `dput(descr_subset[1:10, ])`. Or try to find another subset that does reproduce the problem, and share that using `dput`.

Comment: Ok, I subsetted the data frame and the output of dput looks like that (only for variable F260101_co): 
```(c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("nie", "seltener als jede zweite Woche", "etwa jede zweite Woche einmal", "ein-/zweimal pro Woche", "fast täglich"), class = c("labelled", "factor"), label = "question1")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just saw this... I fixed the issue, you can install from github using remotes or devtools:

```
remotes::install_github("dcomtois/summarytools", ref="master")
```

If you prefer waiting for next CRAN release, a temporary workaround would be something like this:

```
view(dfSummary(df, max.string.width = 50))
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I installed it via ```remotes``` but unfortunately the issue didn't disappear. I also tried to use ```max.string.width``` before, with no effect. Any ideas why this could be? I am grateful to your reply!

Comment: I might be wrong but this looks like the newly installed package is not taking effect... Could you try removing the package, quitting R/RStudio, restarting R, re-installing the package with remotes and try again, just to rule that out?

Comment: Hey, that last thing worked out! I did some plots and the issue mentioned above do not appear for now,. I keep on testing. All the best!

Comment: Excellent, glad it worked! (btw I think the other solution should work too now, I might have commited the change on the wrong branch previously).